# Color in a figure LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, fill

I want to draw three circles as in this figure[image] so I write the following code:

```
$\begin{array}{lcr}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\filldraw[draw=black,fill=gray!20]
\draw  (4,4) circle (1) ;
\draw (7,4) circle (1) ;
\draw (10,4) circle (1) ;
\draw (3,4) -- (5,4) ;
\draw (6,4) -- (8,4) ;
\draw (9,4) -- (11,4);
\draw (3.4,4.8) -- (4.6,4.8);
\draw (3.4,3.2) -- (4.6,3.2);
\draw (6.15,4.5) -- (7.85,4.5);
\draw (6.15,3.5) -- (7.85,3.5);
\draw  (9.01,4.2) -- (10.99,4.2);
\draw  (9.01,3.8) -- (10.99,3.8);
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\quad n=3 \hspace{2cm} n=11\hspace{2cm} n=101
\end{array}$
```

My problem that I want to add the gray color as in the above figure. Can someone please help me to do this?

Comment: I think the solution to your problem is a combination of clipping and scopes. I think I will be able to come up with a working solution in some minutes.

Answer (score 4):

I think the following code should do the trick.
The `clip` option reduces the space in which the drawing is done to the area
of the circle. Therefore you can draw a rectangle over it and just the area inside the circle will be filled. Thus, you also don't have to calculate the exact points on the edge of circle for your lines.

Finally, you need the scopes to reset the clipping area and draw the next circle. The tikz/pgf documentation is quite good and also has a lot of examples. It's really worth reading.

For the next time, please provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). That helps us a lot in helping you and spares time. Your code was close enough to it and you are new here, so I solved it anyway. But the next time, people might request it before answering.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

 $\begin{array}{lcr}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
    \draw[clip]  (4,4) circle (1);
    \filldraw[draw=black, gray!20] (3,3.2) rectangle (5,4.8);
    \draw (3,4.8) -- (5,4.8);
    \draw (3,4) -- (5,4);
    \draw (3,3.2) -- (5,3.2);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
    \draw[clip] (7,4) circle (1);
    \filldraw[draw=black, gray!20] (5,4.5) rectangle (8,3.5);
    \draw (6,4) -- (8,4);
    \draw (6.15,4.5) -- (7.85,4.5);
    \draw (6.15,3.5) -- (7.85,3.5);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
    \draw[clip] (10,4) circle (1) ;
    \filldraw[draw=black, gray!20] (8,4.2) rectangle (12,3.8);
    \draw (9,4) -- (11,4);
    \draw  (9.01,4.2) -- (10.99,4.2);
    \draw  (9.01,3.8) -- (10.99,3.8);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\quad n=3 \hspace{2cm} n=11\hspace{2cm} n=101
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

[image: This is the result]

Comment: Why not add the `n=..` labels as nodes placed below the circle?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should not incorporate the whole picture in math mode. It is a problem to align the labels under each circle. Instead I would draw one picture with the three circles and draw the labels attached to them. Apart from that it is a similar solution to what Dave has done, using `scope` and `clip`. In the below there is a command taking some inputs, where the label is optional. Otherwise `x` and `y` is the center and `partgray` a number between 0 and 1 specifying the height of the colored part. Just for fun you can also set the radius and the color.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\partgraycirc[6][]{% [label]{x}{y}{radius}{partgray}{color}
  \begin{scope}
    \clip  (#2,#3) circle (#4);
    \fill[#6] (#2-#4,#3-#4*#5) rectangle +(2*#4,2*#5*#4);
  \end{scope}
  \draw (#2,#3) circle (#4);
  \node[below] at (#2,#3-#4) {#1};
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \partgraycirc[$d=3$]{1}{1}{1.5}{0.9}{red!40}
  \partgraycirc[$d=11$]{3.5}{1}{0.5}{0.5}{green!40}
  \partgraycirc[$d=101$]{6}{1}{1}{0.1}{blue!40}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]